# Possible unintended reference comparison in C#

Tags: c#, variables, methods

I am getting an Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string' on the if statements in the GetPrice method. It shows its highlighted on all the "if (size == "Small")" statements. Here are my variables:

```
drinkType = GetDrinkType();
size = GetDrinkSize();
price = GetPrice(size);

private string GetDrinkType()
        {
            string theDrink;
            theDrink = "None Selected";

            if (rdoCoffee.Checked)
            {
                theDrink = "Coffee";
            }
            else if (rdoCoco.Checked)
            {
                theDrink = "Hot Chocolate";
            }
            else if (rdoSmoothie.Checked)
            {
                theDrink = "Smoothie";
            }

            return theDrink;
        }

        private string GetDrinkSize()
        {
            string theSize;
            theSize = "None Selected";

            if (rdoSmall.Checked)
            {
                theSize = "Small";
            }
            else if (rdoMedium.Checked)
            {
                theSize = "Medium";
            }
            else if (rdoLarge.Checked)
            {
                theSize = "Large";
            }
            return theSize;
        }
        private decimal GetPrice(object size)
        {
            decimal thePrice;
            thePrice = 0;
            if (size == "Small")
            {
                thePrice = 1.25m;
            }
            else if (size == "Medium")
            {
                thePrice = 2.50m;
            }
            else if (size == "Large")
            {
                thePrice = 3.35m;
            }
            return thePrice;
        }
```

Comment: Why are you passing `object` into `GetPrice()` argument? `GetDrinkSize()` explicitly returns `string`.

Answer (score 3):

The `size` parameter is declared of type `object`, so the compiler doesn't know it's actually of type `string`. So it uses the default equality for type `object`, which is a reference comparison.

If you change the type of `size` to `string`, it will use the equality operator overload from the `string` class, which performs a value comparison.

```
private decimal GetPrice(string size)
```

Comment: Quick follow up question. Would casting the object as string still throw the error or would the compiler not reach that far?

Comment: @Pogrindis, it's just a warning, not an error. But casting to string will suppress the warning and produce the correct result, because then you would be comparing two values that are statically known to be strings, so the compiler would call the correct `==` overload.

Answer (score 1):

The warning occurs because you are comparing a string to an object. If you change

```
 if (size == "Small")
```

to

```
 if (size.ToString() == "Small")
```

the warning will be removed.

Comment: This worked thanks! I guess I didn't realize that I was doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the "object" in GetPrice to "string".

Comment: This also worked and I think this way is better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since in `GetPrize`, the type of `size` is `object`, but you are comparing it to a `string` with `size == "Large"`.

Change the comparison with `"string text".Equals(object)` as shown below

```
private decimal GetPrice(object size)
{
      decimal thePrice = 0m;
      if ("Small".Equals(size))
      {
            thePrice = 1.25m;
      }
      else if ("Medium".Equals(size))
      {
            thePrice = 2.50m;
      }
      else if ("Large".Equals(size))
      {
            thePrice = 3.35m;
      }
      return thePrice;
}
```